# Inserindo uma string em uma lista de ints

Tags: python, loop

Tenho a seguinte regra:

Crie uma função que receba uma lista de inteiros, e que faça a substituição dos itens como abaixo:

- se Multiplo de 3 = 'Fizz'
- se multiplo de 5 = 'Buzz'
- se multiplo de 3 e 5 = 'Fizzbuzz'

Criei o programa abaixo:

```
    intList = list()
intList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]
newlist=list()

def fizzbuzz( lista ):
   for item in lista:
       if item % 3 == 0 and item % 5 == 0:
           lista.remove(item)
           newlist.append(item) ='fizzbuzz'
       elif  item % 3 == 0:
           lista.remove(item)
           newlist.append(item) ='fizz'
       elif  item % 5 == 0:
           lista.remove(item)
           newlist.append(item)='buzz'
       else:
           newlist.append(item)=item


fizzbuzz(newlist)
```

Mas retorna o seguinte erro:

C:\Python27\my_scripts>for_loop.py
  File "C:\Python27\my_scripts\for_loop.py", line 15
    newlist.append(item)='buzz'
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Alguma idéia do que posso fazer?
Ao final do programa preciso apresenta a lista com os inteiros e as strings.

Valeu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **SyntaxError:** can't assign to function call

Esse erro está acontecendo pois você está tentando atribuir um valor numa chamada de função.

Ex:

```
newlist.append(item) ='fizzbuzz'
```

Você está tentando atribuir um valor na função `append`.

Como mencionado pelo @TNT, você tem que alterar sua sintaxe.

```
intList = list()
intList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]
newlist=list()

def fizzbuzz( lista ):
   for item in lista:
       if item % 3 == 0 and item % 5 == 0:
           lista.remove(item)
           newlist.append('fizzbuzz')
       elif  item % 3 == 0:
           lista.remove(item)
           newlist.append('fizz')
       elif  item % 5 == 0:
           lista.remove(item)
           newlist.append('buzz')
       else:
           newlist.append(item)

fizzbuzz(intList)

print(newlist)
```

**Exemplo Funcional**
https://repl.it/DyIS/1

Comment: Muito obrigado L..

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho experiência em Python, mas acredito que as 4 chamadas de "append" estão erradas.
Tente mudar

```
newlist.append(item) ='fizzbuzz'
```

para

```
newlist.append('fizzbuzz')
```

Comment: Muito obrigado TNT! Funcionou, valeu!

Comment: Plz, se possível marque como respondido e dê uma nota para cima. Obrigado!

Comment: Eu tentei TNT, mas somente uma resposta pode ser marcada como correta, a nota para cima tb não esta disponivel para mim pq é necessário nível 15 de reputação para poder marca-la.